# Error in my source code (website connect firebase)

Tags: javascript, firebase

I want to connect the website to firebase.
I have created login page but show error.

Please find error in my source code

Its showing error in addevenlisterner

> index.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>  'addEventListener' of undefined
> at index.js:19
> (anonymous) @ index.js:19

How to solve this issue?

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Lets Barter</title>
    <style>
        
        </style>
                    

                
            <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.6/firebase-app.js"></script>
            <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.6/firebase-auth.js"></script>
            <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.6/firebase-database.js"></script>
            <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.6/firebase-storage.js"></script>
 </head>      <!-- STYLE CSS -->
   <body>

     <form action="">
         <h3>Login</h3>
         <div class="wrapper">
             <input id=Email type="email" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-control">
             <i class ="zmdi zmdi-email"></i>

             <input id=Password type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" class="form-control">
             <i class ="zmdi zmdi-lock"></i>
             <div class="form-group container-login100-form-btn">
                 <button class="w3-button w3-red" id="btn-login" type="button">
                     Login
                 </button>
             </div>

             
             <div class="w-full text-center " style=" font-size : 15px;">
                <span class="text-muted">
                    Forgot 
                </span>
            <a href ="forgot.html" class ="text-dark">
                Username/Password
            </a></div>



         </div>
     </form>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
     <script>
         firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
if (user){    
    window.location.href="home.html";
}
         });
     </script>
   </body>

</html>
```

**indx.js**

```
  var firebaseConfig = 
  {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBunAb5j1E5sFCmEs7r2KWgzSJseuSpDxo",
    authDomain: "let-s-barter-application.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://let-s-barter-application.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "let-s-barter-application",
    storageBucket: "let-s-barter-application.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "189735849114",
    appId: "1:189735849114:web:958819c111f25bf0ace323",
    measurementId: "G-67GC8JVQBX"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL;


var btn = document.getElementById("btn-login").val;
btn.addEventListener("click", function() 
{
var email=document.getElementById("Email").val;
var password=document.getElementById("Password").val;



if(email !="" && password!="")
{
window.alert("Fill out");
}
else{
  
  window.location('home.html');
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```js
> var btn = document.getElementById("btn-login").val;
> ```

You cannot add an event listener to the value of a button, only to the button itself. You should do

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn-login");
```

Additonally, as far as I know

1. Buttons do not have a value
2. To access the value of an input element, you have to use `input.value` and not `input.val`.